# The difference between "process" and "operation"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

In this sentence

> The factory is in the (process - operation) of moving to new offices

I think it is "process" but my teacher told me that it's "operation" ... So which one is correct?

Comment: I think that progressive aspect already conveys the "process".

Comment: Note that *X is in **operation*** means *X **works*** (it's up and running; functioning as intended). But *X is in **process*** is a fairly common alternative to [*X is in **progress***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+in+progress%2Cis+in+process&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20progress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20process%3B%2Cc0) (it's being developed / fixed, probably so that it ***will be*** functional at some future time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Process](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/process)* is correct there, not *operation*. It refers to a series of actions you take to achieve something in your example sentence.